# Optimize multiple weighted matrix multiplications summations

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, eigen3, blas

I have to calculate the linear sum of multiple matrix multiplications, i.e.,

F = A1 * X@Y + A2 * X@Z + A3 * Y@Z

Where X, Y and Z are large matrices and A1, A2 and A3 are scalars.

I can calculate them one by using BLAS routines and add them together, but I assume that by doing some loop optimizations that should perform better(or maybe even not?). Is there any resource that can guide me as to how to go about this rather than just brute forcing it?

Edit:
To expand upon this, this computation is part of a larger problem, and this particular segment is called thousands of times. The matrices are each larger than L3 cache, but fit into main memory.

Comment: Do you have any specific knowledge of the matrices, e.g. sparse, triangular, diagonal, etc.?

Comment: @lorro They don't follow such special properties. They are produced by stochastic processes, and for testing you can imagine generating large random matrices.

Comment: Then I wouldn't bet that you can do better than a library maintained for ages (blas). However, if you're multiplying multiple matrices (not just two), then you might speed that up using dynamic programming based on associativity.

Comment: I don't have to multiply more than 2 matrices, so DP matrix tricks don't apply :(. (I think eigen already does this, so it wouldn't be something I would even code for).

Comment: One obvious optimization would be to compute either `X @ (A1*Y + A2*Z) + A3 * Y@Z` -- or factor out `Z` the same way.

Comment: What matrix size are we talking about? As long as everything fits into L3 cache, we probably don't need to do any more than optimize temporary memory allocations

Comment: Much larger than L3, but not large enough to force out of core computation.